"Go from/on" the other side
If someone had their camera set up in front of them and then someone walked in front of it and ended up ruining their picture/video, would this sentence work:

Dude, you could've "gone from/on the other side".

If one side of the floor's wet, so you instead "go from/on the other side" to not track your footprints across the floor.
If you're sitting next to someone and they get up out of their seat to leave, instead of getting out on their own side, they "leave from/on your side" instead.
P.s. I've put quotes around the phrase that I'm slightly unsure about. I did a Google search and I got a few hits for the phrase "go from the other side".

Perhaps "Dude, you could have gone the other way round."

"On" is fine for most of these examples. "From" would not be a big mistake, but it wouldn't be a great choice for the first two. It might make sense in the last "getting out of a seat" choice.
In all these cases there's motion, from place A to place B. "From" is used when we talk about place A—where we've come from. The place you started, not where you're going. When walking around a camera or wet floor, we're telling the person where to go, which route to choose.
Another great choice in situations like these is "by." We might still say "on the other side" since "on" often goes with "side," but in general, when talking about the route from point A to point B, "by" is good for talking about how you get there. It's very common in discussing driving directions: "Dude, you could have gone by the beltway instead of Main Street."

A more concise option: “You could have gone around.”
